# When importing from a library, Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

There are a number of questions out there for "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use `<Route>` outside a `<Router>`", but this one differs in that it only occurs when using a component from a library that returns a `<Route>`.

My intent is to create a `<GuardedRoute>` component in a private library that others at my company can install using `npm`. This new component returns a `<Route>`, but checks the return value of a predicate first; if the check fails, the `<Route>` will point to some alternative page component. A simple use case is to check whether the user is authenticated. If so, whatever is in `component` will get rendered; if not, the alternative page component, a login screen, will be rendered.

The `<GuardedRoute>` component works just fine if it is sitting somewhere in the app that is using it. However, if that same component is in a library, and the app `import`s `<GuardedRoute>` from the library instead of from its own project directory structure, then I get:

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>
```

The stack trace isn't much help; the most recent relevant piece of it is throwing on `ReactDOM.render()` in `index.tsx`.

The library is compiled into JS and then installed into the app using `npm i path/to/library/on/my/filesystem`.

index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';

import './index.css';



function __init() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
__init();
```

App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { ReportDirectoryActivity } from 'components/activities/ReportDirectoryActivity/ReportDirectoryActivity';
import { AuthActivity } from 'components/activities/AuthActivity/AuthActivity';
import { LogoutActivity } from 'components/activities/LogoutActivity/LogoutActivity';
import { PrivateRoute } from 'components/shared/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';



export const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>

        <Route
          exact
          path="/auth"
          component={AuthActivity} />

        <Route
          exact
          path="/logout"
          component={LogoutActivity} />

        <PrivateRoute
          exact
          path="/"
          component={ReportDirectoryActivity} />

      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

PrivateRoute.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

import {
  RouteProps,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';

// if this line is changed to refer to an identical component within the app, this works fine
import { GuardedRoute } from 'my-library/GuardedRoute';



export interface IPrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {}

export const PrivateRoute: React.FC<IPrivateRouteProps> = props => {
  // using a pass-through fnGuard() just to test
  return (
    <GuardedRoute
      {...props}
      fnGuard={() => true}
      elFailure={(
        <Redirect to="/auth" />
      )} />
  );
};
```

GuardedRoute.tsx (located in the library)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

import {
  Route,
  RouteProps
} from 'react-router-dom';



export interface IGuardedRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  fnGuard: () => boolean;
  elFailure: JSX.Element;
}

export const GuardedRoute: React.FC<IGuardedRouteProps> = props => {
  const restProps = _.cloneDeep(props);
  delete restProps.fnGuard;
  delete restProps.elFailure;

  const Component = props.component;
  function renderComponent(renderProps: any) {
    return Component ? (
      <Component {...renderProps} />
    ) : null;
  }

  return (
    <Route
      {...restProps}
      render={renderProps => props.fnGuard() ?
        renderComponent(renderProps) :
        props.elFailure} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The library needs to specify in its webpack config that `react-router-dom` can be used from external dependencies.

add the following to your library webpack config

```
externals: {
     'react': 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    'react-router-dom': 'react-router-dom' // Add this too apart from react
},
```

Comment: Please let me know if the solution works for you or not?

Comment: I tried this out but it didn't work. I don't believe webpack is used for the library; I am just compiling to JS and importing those JS files. Webpack is only used when running the library as a standalone app.

Comment: What are you using to compile the files?

Comment: `tsc --no-emit false`.
`outDir` is set to a folder called `dist/`, which is where the other app includes the files from.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty because although this didn't solve the issue, I believe this answer is on the right track.

Comment: @derefed just commenting that I'm getting the same error you are. Hoping to find an answer too! Wondering if it's a react-dom specific issue or it happens with other libraries too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019924/issue-creating-shared-react-router-component-with-create-react-app-error-inva

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your library code is throwing the error because it doesn't see a router component as the parent.

Perhaps you can create a `GuardedComponent` that wraps the passed `Component` rather than extending the route? This code is untested but just for a general idea.

```
interface IGuardedComponentProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
  fnGuard: () => boolean;
  elFailure: JSX.Element;
}

export const GuardedComponent: React.FC<IGuardedComponentProps> = props => {
  const { children, fnGuard, elFailure } = props;

  return (
    <>{fnGuard() ? elFailure : children}</>
  );
};
```

Then you would use it like

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
>
  <GuardedComponent
    fnGuard={() => true}
    elFailure={(
      <Redirect to="/auth" />
    )} />
  >
    <ReportDirectoryActivity />
  </GuardedComponent>
</Route>
```

Answer (score -3):

According to the documentation of [React Route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router), you *should* use `<Route>` component **inside** `<Router>`.

The simplest way to do this is to wrap you `App` component into `Router` in you `index.tsx` file:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';

import './index.css';



function __init() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
       <App />
      </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
__init();
```

Comment: Please read the code I posted carefully. App.tsx, which is the root of all other components in the app, wraps everything in a Router.