# Issue creating shared react router component with create-react-app - Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, shared

I'm getting an error when trying to render react-router as a shared component (and have any idea why it isn't working but wanted to confirm.)

I wanted to make a shared NavBar for two similar react apps using create-react-app. When I pull out the component with a `<Link>` element into a shared component I get the Invariant error because it can't see that I'm calling it within `<BrowserRouter>`

My thought is you can't have any shared components that use react-router because they need to see in the same directory that `<BrowserRouter>` is available? Is that the case (or is there a way to fix this and I'm doing it wrong).

Help appreciated!

My index.ts in (app/src)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

my App.tsx (in app/src)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from '../../common/src/NavBar/NavBar'; // this only works if it's ./NavBar/NavBar in same src directory
import Footer from '../../common/src/Footer/Footer'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar/>
        <p>Work in progress.</p>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

my NavBar.tsx (in common/src and transpile with react-app-rewired and removeModuleScopePlugin(), or compiled and in common/lib as NavBar.js and imported - I get the same error both ways)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary fixed-top">
      <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
        Logo
      </Link>
      <div>
        description
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: You probably need to specify externals in your build. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491342/when-importing-from-a-library-invariant-failed-you-should-not-use-route-outs/61606938#61606938

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hey! I tried that but the library I'm compiling from isn't using webpack so it doesn't seem like that's the issue